# C++: declaring an extern vector container in header file causes errors

Tags: c++, class, vector, header, extern

I tried searching for solution but couldn't find.

So I have a header file `items.h`:

```
#ifndef ITEMS_H
#define ITEMS_H

#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int create_item();


class itemClass
{

public:

    short int xTile;
    short int yTile;

    bool playerHas;

    short int category;
    short int weaponCategory;


}extern vector<itemClass> items;


#endif
```

and then I have `items.cpp` where I try to use this vector in `create_item()`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include "items.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector<itemClass> items;

int index = 0;

int create_item()
{
    //select category for the created item
    short int itemCategory = rand() % 3;

    switch(itemCategory)
    {
    case WEAPON:

        //increase weapons list by one
        items.resize(items.size() + 1);

        index = items.size();

        //set appropriate item category
        items.at(index).category = itemCategory;

        items.at(index).weaponCategory = rand() % 9;

        break;

     }
```

I left out some non-important parts out. Anyway this code works fine as long as I don't declare the vector as extern in the header, but just keep it local. Why does it cause errors when I try to do this?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to include errors:

> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(12): error
>   C2371: 'items' : redefinition; different basic types
>
> 1>
>   c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.h(53) : see
>   declaration of 'items'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(36): error
>   C2228: left of '.resize' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(36): error
>   C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(38): error
>   C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(41): error
>   C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(41): error
>   C2228: left of '.category' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(43): error
>   C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(43): error
>   C2228: left of '.weaponCategory' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(46): error
>   C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(46): error
>   C2228: left of '.weaponCategory' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(47): error
>   C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(47): error
>   C2228: left of '.weaponCategory' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(48): error
>   C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>          type is 'int'
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(48): error
>   C2228: left of '.weaponCategory' must have class/struct/union
>
> 1>c:\users\aske\documents\c++\roguelike\roguelike\items.cpp(50): error
>   C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Put a semicolon before `extern`, as in `};extern vector<itemClass> items;`

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. Now I feel ashamed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `;` before `extern` in the `items.h` file, then it should compile - but you really don't need to define the items vector in the .h file.